# jquery - text not switching on first click, then works fine

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I have a quick little toggle that changes the text of a button when somebody clicks on it. It's working, but not on the first click, for some reason? Second click onward, it works fine. Any thoughts?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-archive-header").click(function(){
        var text = $(this).text() == 'VIEW ARCHIVE' ? 'CLOSE ARCHIVE' : 'VIEW ARCHIVE';
        $(this).text(text);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-archive-header">
    VIEW ARCHIVE
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use **$.trim()**

```
$.trim($(this).text());
```

so your code will be

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-archive-header").click(function(){
        var text = ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'VIEW ARCHIVE') ? 'CLOSE ARCHIVE' : 'VIEW ARCHIVE';
        $(this).text(text);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ubpcrnkx/)

Comment: Using `$.trim()` is not an efficient way of doing it because it will add a overhead to every click while it is only needed for the first. Fixing the value is obviously a much better approach. However, in cases where the value is coming from other resources (e.g. Ajax call) and contains spaces, `$.trim()` is a nice way fix it, but then I would apply it to the source (e.g. the data from the Ajax call) so it is only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces in the value. Remove them and it works.

Change this:

```
<div class="btn-archive-header">
    VIEW ARCHIVE
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="btn-archive-header">VIEW ARCHIVE</div>
```

Here is how your code should be:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-archive-header").click(function(){
        var text = $(this).text() == 'VIEW ARCHIVE' ? 'CLOSE ARCHIVE' : 'VIEW ARCHIVE';
        $(this).text(text);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-archive-header">VIEW ARCHIVE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.trim()` JavaScript method on the text obtained from the element:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-archive-header").click(function(){
        var text = $(this).text().trim() == 'VIEW ARCHIVE' ? 'CLOSE ARCHIVE' : 'VIEW ARCHIVE';
        $(this).text(text);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-archive-header">
    VIEW ARCHIVE
</div>
```